# overloading with both widening and boxing

Tags: java, overloading

```
public void add(long... x){}
public void add(Integer... x){}

add(2);
```

this produces error...why overlaoding is not performed  with both widening and boxing?

but overloading without vararg works fine

```
public void add(long x){}
    public void add(Integer x){}

    add(2);
```

here add(long x) will be executed that is widening beats boxing...why not same concept with
var arguments

Comment: Works fine for me. Which error do you see? What is your java version? Is there a chance that you are using java prior to 5?

Comment: i am using java 6 ..boxig is only from java 5..widening is from before java 5..so widening is choosen before boxing and var arg to not violate pre existing codes(before java 5)

Comment: it is ambiguous clearly @AlexR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java compiler performs three attempts to choose an appropriate method overload ([JLS §15.12.2.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.1)):

- Phase 1: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Subtyping
  (possible boxing conversions and methods with varargs are ignored)
- Phase 2: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Method
  Invocation Conversion
  (takes boxing conversion in account, but ignores methods with varargs)
- Phase 3: Identify Applicable Variable Arity Methods
  (examines all possibilities)

So, with your examples it works as follows:

- Without varargs: `add(long x)` is identified as the only applicable method on the 1st phase (this method is applicable by subtyping since `int` is a subtype of `long`, [§JLS 4.10.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.1)), so that following phases are not executed.
- With varargs: overload resoltion algorithm goes to phase 3, where both methods are identified as applicable, and compiler can't choose the most specific method of them (choosing the most specific method is yet another complex algorithm), therefore it reports ambiguity.

**See also:**

- [The Java Language Specification, Seventh Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

because it is **ambiguous**.

`2` can be `Integer` as well as `long` and it can be resolve to both. you made compiler confused whom to invoke :)

---

### 5.12.2.2 Choose the Most Specific Method

> If more than one method declaration is
>   both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to
>   choose one to provide the descriptor
>   for the run-time method dispatch. The
>   Java programming language uses the
>   rule that the most specific method is
>   chosen. The informal intuition is that
>   one method declaration is more
>   specific than another if any
>   invocation handled by the first method
>   could be passed on to the other one
>   without a compile-time type error.
>
> The precise definition is as follows.
>   Let m be a name and suppose that there
>   are two declarations of methods named
>   m, each having n parameters. Suppose
>   that one declaration appears within a
>   class or interface T and that the
>   types of the parameters are T1, . . .
>   , Tn; suppose moreover that the other
>   declaration appears within a class or
>   interface U and that the types of the
>   parameters are U1, . . . , Un. Then
>   the method m declared in T is more
>   specific than the method m declared in
>   U if and only if both of the following
>   are true:
>
> T can be converted to U by method
>   invocation conversion. Tj can be
>   converted to Uj by method invocation
>   conversion, for all j from 1 to n. A
>   method is said to be maximally
>   specific for a method invocation if it
>   is applicable and accessible and there
>   is no other applicable and accessible
>   method that is more specific. If there
>   is exactly one maximally specific
>   method, then it is in fact the most
>   specific method; it is necessarily
>   more specific than any other method
>   that is applicable and accessible. It
>   is then subjected to some further
>   compile-time checks as described in
>   §15.12.3.
>
> It is possible that no method is the
>   most specific, because there are two
>   or more maximally specific methods. In
>   this case:
>
> If all the maximally specific methods
>   have the same signature, then: If one
>   of the maximally specific methods is
>   not declared abstract, it is the most
>   specific method. Otherwise, all the
>   maximally specific methods are
>   necessarily declared abstract. The
>   most specific method is chosen
>   arbitrarily among the maximally
>   specific methods. However, the most
>   specific method is considered to throw
>   a checked exception if and only if
>   that exception is declared in the
>   throws clauses of each of the
>   maximally specific methods. Otherwise,
>   we say that the method invocation is
>   ambiguous, and a compile-time error
>   occurs.

**15.12.2.3 Example: Overloading Ambiguity**

```
Consider the example:
class Point { int x, y; }
class ColoredPoint extends Point { int color; }

class Test {
    static void test(ColoredPoint p, Point q) {
        System.out.println("(ColoredPoint, Point)");
    }
    static void test(Point p, ColoredPoint q) {
        System.out.println("(Point, ColoredPoint)");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColoredPoint cp = new ColoredPoint();
        test(cp, cp);                                           // compile-time error
    }
}
```

This example produces an error at compile time. The problem is that there are two declarations of test that are applicable and accessible, and neither is more specific than the other. Therefore, the method invocation is ambiguous.
If a third definition of test were added:

```
static void test(ColoredPoint p, ColoredPoint q) {
    System.out.println("(ColoredPoint, ColoredPoint)");
}
```

then it would be more specific than the other two, and the method invocation would no longer be ambiguous.

- [Read More](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html)

Comment: Specifically, one method is not any more specific than the other. (`System.out.println(new char[] { 'x' });` works as expected, not bothering with `PrintStream.println(Object)`.) Method overloading - avoid if reasonable to do so.

Comment: Jigar, I most your answers are very good but I think that in this case you are wrong. Java know to distinguish between long and int very well. Constant 5 is int, 5L is long. So these 2 methods are not ambiguous. I tried his code and it compiled and ran fine. What is strange is that it always calls the long version. When I changed Integer to int it started to behavior "correctly".

Comment: @Alex Thanks :) . I even tried the same code and its failing to compile for me , Check [this](http://ideone.com/x0Eic)