# Error removing an item from an ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to remove a value from the list using thread. But the code fails and gives an exception. Plz help I'm a beginner in thread programming.....

This is the content of `Test.java`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    private static final List<Integer> Values = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestThread t1 = new TestThread(Values);
        t1.start();

        System.out.println(Values.size());
    }
}
```

This is the content of `TestThread.java`

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestThread extends Thread {
    private final List<Integer> Values;

    public TestThread(List<Integer> v) {
        this.Values = v;
        Values.add(5);
    }

    public void run() {
        Values.remove(5);
        System.out.println("5 removed");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception, and what line is causing it?

Comment: 1Exception in thread "Thread-0" 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:603)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:444)
 at TestThread.run(TestThread.java:12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line means: *remove the value at index 5*. But there's nothing in index 5.

```
    Values.remove(5);
```

There's only 1 value in the array currently because this line means *add the value 5 into my list*, not add 5 values to my list.

```
    Values.add(5);
```

Your error is most likely `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You'll see it more clearly if you display the size of your list.

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Values.size()); // should give you 1
    Values.remove(5);
    System.out.println("5 removed");
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

When it was inserted, 5 got auto-boxed into an Integer object. Thus, to successfully remove it, you should wrap it into one: `new Integer(5)`. Then issue the remove call. It will then invoke the overloaded version of remove that accepts an Object, instead of the int.

```
Values.remove(new Integer(5));
```

means *Remove the Integer object named '5' from my list*.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

`List#remove(int)` method removes the element at the specified position from the list, so `Values.remove(5)` will try to remove at index 5 element which element does exist there. Here `int` value 5 will not be autoboxed as `List#remove(int)` is already exist.

you should use `List#remove(Object o)`  which actually `Values.remove(new Integer(5))` .

```
public void run() {
    Values.remove(new integer(5));
    System.out.println("5 removed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `Values.remove(5);` isn't doing what you expect it to do. The int you're passing in the parameter is an index value, so it's trying to delete the item at index 5 in your arraylist, but there is only 1 value in it.

A workaround to enable you to remove an integer of a given value

```
int given = 5;
for (int curr = 0; curr < Values.size(); curr++){
    if (Values.get(curr) == given) {
         Values.remove(given);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In [List (ArrayList)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) there are 2 `remove` methods (overloaded)

1. `remove(int)` --> which means remove at index
2. `remove(Object)` --> which means remove the particular object from list

When you said `Values.remove(5)`, the compiler took 5 as `int` and invoked the `remove(int)` method, which tried to remove the value store at index 5. Since the index 5, dint had any value, `IndexOutOfBoundException` was thrown.

To tackle it, say `remove(new Integer(5))`, to make compiler, invoke remove(Object) method. 
See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803553/which-method-is-called-integer-a-vs-int-a-int-b) for more clarity.