# Java Method Overloading with Boxing/Widening

Tags: java, overloading, scjp

I am working on Java Se 7 OCA and could not figure out why below code does not compile. aMethod call in main method gives compile error stating ambiguous method. Precedence rules between widening and boxing seems to clash in this overloading method sample.

```
public class Overloading {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Byte i = 5;
    byte k = 5;
    aMethod(i, k);
}

static void aMethod(byte i, Byte k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 1");
}

static void aMethod(byte i, int k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 2");
}

static void aMethod(Byte i, Byte k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 3 ");
}
}
```

The error is "**The method aMethod(byte, Byte) is ambiguous for the type Overloading**". 
when I comment out first method, it gives same error for second method.

My thinking is:
First method needs unboxing and boxing
Second method needs unboxing and widening
Third method needs only boxing.
So it must be third method, since it needs the least conversion and all of them have boxing conversion.

Comment: And the error message was?

Comment: Why do you think this *should* compile?

Comment: You can find a proper explanation of the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4921807/1065197. Since compiler will go to phase 3, it will find more than a suitable method to use, thus being ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with all these methods:

```
static void aMethod(byte i, Byte k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 1");
}

static void aMethod(byte i, int k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 2");
}

static void aMethod(Byte i, Byte k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 3 ");
}
```

Java doesn't know, which one it should invoke in line:

```
    aMethod(i, k);
```

Your params `i` and `k` could be converted by various ways, according to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) specifications:

`i` could be `unboxed` to `byte` (5.1.8) or leaved as `Byte` (5.1.1) -> 2 variants

`k` could be `boxed` into `Byte` (5.1.7) or widened to `int` type (5.1.2) -> 2 variants.

Comment: You are right; but conversion have precedence rules. it will choose widening over boxing. And it must leave "i" as Byte when appropriate than unboxing it.

Comment: @isaolmez The only one precedence, which will work here, is rule 5.1.1 (conversion type to the same type). In case, when you have not method with appropriate signature (i.e. `aMethod(Byte i, byte k)`) this precedence has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

this class you have two equal method

```
static void aMethod(Byte i, Byte k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 3 ");
}

static void aMethod(byte i, Byte k) {
    System.out.println("Inside 1");
}
```

Byte automatic conversion byte ，so  compile error

Comment: In fact, my call is ambiguous, methods are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not the definition, but the call is ambiguous.
since, all the integers in java by default are, int. even if you say byte b =5, 5 would be internally converted to int for any operation. But as the reference is byte, in you case, it has option to call method 2 & 3. So compiler cant understand what to call.

so `aMethod(i, (Byte)k)` should work.

Comment: I assume you suggested aMethod(i, (int)k). But in this case there are no other options for this call. only integer accepting method is the second one.

Comment: don't assume. as i said, all integer literals are by default converted to int, be it short, byte, long. so through reference compiler sees byte, but from value it sees an int. Thats y the ambiguity is created. So here, aMethod(i, (byte)k) would work, or else you might need to pass an value of type int. This you can verify by calling aMethod(i, 5) and aMethod(i, (byte)5);

Comment: aMethod(i, (byte)5); did not compile and gave the same error. But if I use aMethod(i, 5), it compiles.

Comment: oops.... did i write (byte)k.... it should be (Byte)k. As explicit casting and auto-boxing are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Following points should be kept in mind while method overloading in Java:

1. Widening of primitive types uses the immediate next wider type
   method argument, if exact match is not found.
2. Boxing and var-args are compatible with method overloading if they
   are used individually.
3. One wrapper type can't be widened to another. For example, Integer
   can't be widened to Long.
4. Widening followed by boxing does not work. For example, an int can't
   be passed to a Long.
5. Boxing followed by widening works only in one situation if boxed
   argument is passed to an Object type reference. An int can be passed
   to an Object, via Integer.
6. Var-args can be combined with either widening or boxing, but
   carefully.

In above piece of code the arguments passed to aMethod should be appropriately type-casted, because intermediate results in Java are converted in int in an int expression.