# Mockito: Verifying overloaded methods with type-compatible arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito, overload-resolution, ecj

Consider you want to **mock** an interface using `Mockito` containing the following method signatures:

```
public void doThis(Object o);

public void doThis(Object... o)
```

I need to **verify** that `doThis(Object o)` (and not the other method) has been invoked exactly one time.

First I thought that the following line would do the trick:

```
verify(mock, times(1)).doThis(anyObject());
```

However, as this seems to work on Windows, it doesn't on Linux because in this environment, a call to of the other `doThis` method is expected.
This is caused because the **`anyObject()` argument seems to match both method  signatures** and one is chosen in a more or less unpredictable way.

How can I enforce that **Mockito always chooses `doThis(Object o)`** for verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This is not a mockito issue.***

During further investigating, [I realized that the actual method is chosen at compile-time (JLS §15.12.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471499/why-does-the-compiler-prefer-an-int-overload-to-a-varargs-char-overload-for-a-ch). So basically the class files differed between windows and linux which caused different mockito behavior.

The interface is discouraged (see `Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 42`).
I changed it to match the following:

```
public void doThis(Object o);

public void doThis(Object firstObj, Object... others)
```

With this change the expected (first) method will always be chosen.

**One thing is still left:**
Why does the java compiler on windows (eclipse compiler) produce a different output than Oracle JDK javac on Linux?

***This might be a bug in ECJ*** because I would expect that the java language spec is pretty strict here.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you consider javac bug-free-by-definitionTM?  :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree to most from the other answer, just one part hasn't been answered yet: why the difference in compilers?

At a closer look this is not a difference between ecj and javac, but between different versions of JLS:

- compiling at compliance 1.7 or less, both compilers select the first (single argument) method.
- compiling at compliance 1.8, both compilers select the second (varargs) method

Let's have a look at the produced bytecodes:

```
     7: invokestatic  #8                  // Method anyObject:()Ljava/lang/Object;
    10: checkcast     #9                  // class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
    13: invokevirtual #10                 // Method doThis:([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

(both compilers also agree on these bytes)

This is to say: inference in Java 8 has become more powerful and is now able to infer the type argument for `anyObject()` to `Object[]`. This can be seen by the `checkcast` instruction, which translated back into source code reads: `(Object[])anyObject()`. This implies that also `doThis(Object...)` can be invoked without varargs magic, but by passing a single argument of type `Object[]`.

Now both methods are applicable in the same category ("applicable by fixed arity invocation") and search for the most specific among applicable methods selects the second method.

By contrast, Java 7 would allow invoking the second method only as a variable-arity invocation, but this is not even tried if a fixed-arity match is found.

The above also indicates how to make the program robust against the changes in JLS:

```
verify(mock, times(1)).doThis(Matchers.<Object>anyObject());
```

This will tell all compilers at all versions to select the first method, because now it will always see the argument of `doThis()` as `Object` -- if you really can't avoid this unhealthy overload, that is :)