# Mockito verifies wrong overloaded method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, overloading

I'm trying to write a unit test for a class that uses as a dependency an [`AsynchronousSocketChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html):

```
final AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = mock(AsynchronousSocketChannel.class);
final Client client = new Client(channel);

client.read();
verify(channel).read(isA(ByteBuffer.class), eq(client), isA(CompletionHandler.class));
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
5 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

This happens because `AsynchronousSocketChannel.read` has 4 different overloaded versions, and for some reason `verify` keeps choosing the one with 5 arguments, even if the matchers I'm passing match the version with `read(ByteBuffer dst, A attachment, CompletionHandler<Integer,? super A> handler)`.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265732/mockito-verifying-overloaded-methods-with-type-compatible-arguments#34322438) it's suggested that this could really be a problem with the actual compiler, and that it's possible to instruct the compiler to choose the right overloaded method with something like

```
verify(channel).read(
        ArgumentMatchers.<ByteBuffer>isA(ByteBuffer.class),
        ArgumentMatchers.<Client>eq(client),
        ArgumentMatchers.<CompletionHandler>isA(CompletionHandler.class)
);
```

but doing this I keep getting the same error.

Any idea if it's possible to make this work? Otherwise I believe I could just use the 5 params overloading, passing `null` as the additional 2 params, but it would be a bit like a hack to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to set expectations on a [`final` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler)).

```
public final <A> void read(ByteBuffer dst,
            A attachment,
            CompletionHandler<Integer,? super A> handler)
```

Mockito can't override that method in the mock, so it's actually calling the real method. And that method is calling through to the overload with 5 parameters, and it's in that method where it is interacting with the mockito framework.

If you can construct the `Client` with an [`AsynchronousByteChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousByteChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler)) instead of a `AsynchronousSocketChannel`, you could use that instead. This would work as you expect, because the 3-parameter overload isn't `final` on that class.

Otherwise, all you can do (with Mockito) is to set the expectations of what that 5-parameter overload will be called with.

Comment: Alternatively, the newer version of Mockito 2 allow for *mocking* of **final** things. But it is an experimental feature that requires special "enablement". See http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the issue.