# Passing byte arguments to overloaded method

Tags: java

I took this code snippet from some quiz, using IDE I executed it and get a result **long, long** but the correct answer is **Byte, Byte**, why I got different result? The question is related to JDK 11

```java
public class Client {
    static void doCalc(byte... a) {
        System.out.print("byte...");
    }

    static void doCalc(long a, long b) {
        System.out.print("long, long");
    }

    static void doCalc(Byte s1, Byte s2) {
        System.out.print("Byte, Byte");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte b = 5;
        doCalc(b, b);
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

The code was taken here: [Oracle Certification Overview and Sample Questions](https://education.oracle.com/5278_Java11-Programmer_Study-Guide_V1_E94B.pdf) 
*(Page: 13, Question: 5)*

Comment: Are you sure it is not `Byte b = 5;` with a capital B.

Comment: I get `long, long` on Java8 too FYI... Not sure why to be honest, waiting for an answer too :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Method Overloading with Boxing/Widening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493313/java-method-overloading-with-boxing-widening)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, if you go through the Java language [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) for determining method signature at compile time it will be clear :

> 1. The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion or the use of variable arity
>      method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase
>      then processing continues to the second phase.
> 2. The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable
>      arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this
>      phase then processing continues to the third phase.
> 3. The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

So, from the above steps, it is clear that in your case at **first phase** Java compiler will find a matching method which does `doCalc(long a,long b)`. Your method `doCalc(Byte s1, Byte s2)` needs an autoboxing during the call so it will get less preference.

Comment: Concerning why `long` accepts `byte`, seems to follow a _widening primitive conversion_: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2. So basically, `+widening -boxing -varargs` then `+widening +boxing -varargs` then `+widening +boxing +varargs`.

Comment: @kbo Why do you think that the correct answer is `Byte, Byte`?

Comment: @kbo I guess the _correct answer_ is incorrect :) Might be worth pointing the authors to this question if you can.

Comment: @sp00m I found this question in Oracle's samples, please take a look at edited part

Comment: @kbo Wow... No idea how to proceed then!

Comment: @kbo I believe that docs shared needs to be corrected as code gives the output as per the java language specification

Answer (score 2):

Please have a read of [JLS chapter on conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

What is happening in your case is that during runtime, JVM chooses to perform a **widening conversion** `byte -> long` as this is conversion is safer because it is guaranteed that it does not cause `RuntimeException`.

Converting from `byte` to `Byte` also called **boxing** can result in **OutOfMemoryError** as the JVM has to allocate new objects onto the heap:

> A boxing conversion may result in an OutOfMemoryError if a new instance of one of the wrapper classes (Boolean, Byte, Character, Short, Integer, Long, Float, or Double) needs to be allocated and insufficient storage is available.

Because of that, the safer `byte -> long` **widening conversion** is preferred.

Comment: Just to note, boxing from `byte` to `Byte` never causes `OutOfMemoryException`, since all values of `Byte` (-128 - 127) are internally cached. But it may not be the same with other types, so as the rule of thumb, widening conversion gets priority.

Answer (score 1):

For finding the correct overload, the order is:

1. by number of parameters
2. boxing/unboxing
3. variadic parameters

So

- If `b` where a `Byte` the result would be `Byte, Byte`.
- If passed would have been `new byte[] { b, b }`the result would be `byte, byte`.
- If passed two byte b, a *widening* from byte to int to long is possible and the result is `long, long`.
- When the long, long overload is removed, `Byte, Byte` results.